# open graph sample object, invalid og:type?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, custom-action

I've set up a custom action and custom object. I'm attempting to post to my timeline with the sample code Facebook offers:

```
curl -F 'access_token=<my token>' \
     -F 'photo=http://samples.ogp.me/351656114891990' \
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me/stipple_staging:stipple'
```

The response that comes back is this (parsed out for easier reading):

```
{
    "error":{
        "type":"Exception",
        "message":"Object at URL 'http:\/\/samples.ogp.me\/351656114891990' is invalid because the configured 'og:type' of '103770389680565:photo' is invalid."
    }
}
```

I'm sort of clueless at this point. Is this a known gotcha where I need to do something, or just a bug?

EDIT: Facebook now seems to have fixed this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is that your og:type is supposed to be your app namespace:action type, like

```
<meta property="og:type" content="your_app_namespace:photo" />
```

Check out section IV of the [custom objects walkthrough](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/customopengraph/walkthrough/), it has some examples of how the og:type tag should be formatted. I'm not certain that appid and namespace are the same thing, in the eyes of FB.

On a side note, you can check your FB URL's [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) instead of doing everything through cURL, if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have used fb's debugger, but I'm trying to actually make the action appear in my timeline, so I can submit it for acceptance. I probably should have mentioned that changing the og:type to use my app's namespace makes facebook throw OAuthExceptions, but I wanted to make sure that the code they are generating on their end for their examples was problematic first, which it looks like it is.

Comment: What kind of oauth exceptions are you getting?

Comment: `{"error":{"message":"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.","type":"OAuthException","code":2}}` I'm not sure where I can find the list codes to investigate further, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it easy on yourself, there is a list of allowed values available on the Facebook website. If can use any of them in the type field: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/#types